# Sub Total in MS Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to raise sub total in SQL Query?

Currently I am getting the desired output like this:

```
G.R.N G.R.N Date     CUSTOMER  ItemName Total Cases Total Pallets
1   8/1/2019    Cus A   Item A        66        2
1   8/1/2019    Cus A   Item B       462        13
1   8/1/2019    Cus A   Item C       430        12
10  8/3/2019    Cus B   Item D      553             16
10  8/3/2019    Cus B   Item B       52              2
10  8/3/2019    Cus B   Item E      359              10
```

But I need output like this:

```
G.R.N G.R.N Date  CUSTOMER     ItemName Total Cases Total Pallets
1      8/1/2019    Cus A    Item A       66               2
1      8/1/2019    Cus A    Item B       462          13
1      8/1/2019    Cus A    Item C       430          12
            TOTAL                    958          27
10  8/3/2019   Cus B    Item D       553          16
10  8/3/2019   Cus B    Item B       52                2
10  8/3/2019   Cus B    Item E       359           10
            TOTAL                    964           28
```

I have even tried the Roll up, But no luck

```
select 
T0.BaseNum AS 'G.R.N',
T2.DocDate AS 'G.R.N Date',
T1.WhsName AS 'CUSTOMER_NAME',

T0.ItemName,

sum(t0.quantity) as 'Total Cases',

count (distinct t0.batchnum) as 'Total Pallets'

 from OIBT T0 LEFT JOIN OWHS T1 ON T0.WhsCode = T1.WhsCode
           LEFT JOIN OPDN T2 ON T0.BaseNum = T2.DocNum AND T0.BaseEntry = T2.DocEntry

 where t1.WhsName = 'Cus A' AND t2.DocDate <= '20190827' 

 group by t0.BaseNum,t0.ItemName,T1.WhsName,t2.DocDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grouping sets` to get the rows that you want:

```
group by grouping sets ( (t0.BaseNum, t0.ItemName, T1.WhsName, t2.DocDate),
                         (t0.BaseNum, t2.DocDate)
                       )
```

You can add an `order by`:

```
order by t0.BaseNum, t2.DocDate, grouping(T1.WhsName)
```

Comment: But I am getting this total at the end of the query like this:G.R.N G.R.N Date CUSTOMER ItemName Total Cases Total Pallets
1 8/1/2019 Cus A Item A 66 2
1 8/1/2019 Cus A Item B 462 13
1 8/1/2019 Cus A Item C 430 12
10 8/3/2019 Cus B Item D 553 16
10 8/3/2019 Cus B Item B 52 2
10 8/3/2019 Cus B Item E 359 10
1 8/1/2019 TOTAL  958 27
10 8/3/2019 TOTAL  964 28

Comment: I am getting the total at the end... But I need the total like I have shown in my example